# Extract rows based on only one column using R

Tags: r, subset

Please help, I need to extract data from a table based on one column, 
Here is my table:

```
Col1 Col2  Col3 
1    34    3
1    34    4
2    342   3
2    23    4
```

And what I need

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 
1    34   3
1    34   4
```

But the most important thing, I cannot base subset using value from table like `df_extract<-df[df$Col1==1,]`, my goal to create algorithm which would **automatically detect distinct(unique) value**,and then subset data from table without input `1` or `2` in  query [df$Col1==1,] 
Here how I see it:
1) `df_distinct%>% distinct(Col1)`
2) next step using data from df_distinct, subset data from table

Comment: Not clear about your logic.

Comment: `subset(df, duplicated(Col2) | duplicated(Col2, fromLast = TRUE))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to create your data using the following:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2),
                 col2 = c(34,34,342,23,34,34,342,23),
                 col3 = c(3,4,3,4,3,4,3,4))
```

And, if you wish to subset based on only one column, you can use @kyle-marsh solution

```
> df[df$col1 == 1, ]
  col1 col2 col3
1    1   34    3
2    1   34    4
5    1   34    3
6    1   34    4
```

And, if you need only distinct columns, maybe you can try this

```
> unique(df[df$col1 == 1, ])
  col1 col2 col3
1    1   34    3
2    1   34    4
```

And, if you need to aggregate the data based on `col1`, you can try the following. Since, `col1` is numeric,

```
> aggregate(df[,-1], by = list(col1 = df$col1), sum)
  col1 col2 col3
1    1  136   14
2    2  730   14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your table into a data frame then subset. This might be the easiest way.

Lets call your table "tab", and the new data frame "df".

```
df<-as.data.frame(tab)
```

Now it is a lot easier to subset based on your column of interest.We will make another df called "df_subsetted" by subsetting the df based on a value for Col1.

```
df_subsetted<-df[df$Col1==1,]
```

Or if you want to use the filter function.

```
require(dplyr)
df_subsetted<-filter(df, Col1==1)
```